i'm looking for the direction of using function:torch_directml_native.get_gpu_memory()
i wonder how to use function:torch_directml_native.get_gpu_memory()
include the meaning of it's args and the principle of this function
what should i provide to this function
and what does this function will return
i'm trying to find the source code of this function but failed.
i only find the DLL which includes this function.
but this won't provide any help to my problem

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
